# Detecting cumulative timeout for callouts

Tags: limits

According to the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm):

> The maximum cumulative timeout for callouts by a single Apex
>   transaction is 120 seconds. This time is additive across all callouts
>   invoked by the Apex transaction.

However, I don't see any method under the [Limits Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) to get the time spent on callouts.

Is there anyway to do this?  I have a use case where an integration is making lots of callouts. I'd like to detect the limit and exit if with a safe margin when I get close to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could accumulate the callout time yourself:

```
Long calloutMs = 0;

Long s1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
// Callout 1
Long f2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
calloutMs += (f1 - s1);

Long s2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
// Callout 2
Long f2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
calloutMs += (f2 - s2);

...
```

which while probably not being the same count that the platform makes is probably close enough if you are giving yourself a safe margin.

Comment: that's the approach i started to take... However, it appears that I can catch these exceptions so maybe I don't need to prevent it ahead of time

Comment: still your answer is correct as the question was asked.  I would add to that, if you want to determine if you can callout safely, then add the time to the getTimeout() of the http request

Comment: @NSjonas Yeah perhaps. Not sure what will happen on the callout that times out though. There is a risk that the operation may have completed at the remote side and then you repeat it later thinking it hadn't. Or if you assume it did complete but it returns an error status that you never see then you might have lost the operation.

Comment: ^ good point!  Did not consider that.  Going to stick with the preventative detection

Comment: Any idea why the Limits class doesn't include a method for callout timeout tracking?  Is it because hitting the limit throws a *catchable* exception, unlike some (all?) of the other limits covered by the Limits class's methods?